# ul and li pushing div out of alignment

Tags: css, list, html, html-lists

I have all my divs centered with the left and right edges vertically aligned, but when I added the ul and li then my .nav started to have a background color that extends past the right hand edge. Any idea how to lock this down? max width doesn't prevent it from flowing outwards.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<title></title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

    <div class="header">

    <img src="image/logo.png" width="155" height="110" alt="Big Box Property Preservation" />

    </div>

    <div class="navContainer">


        <div class="miniNav">

        <img src="image/link_banner.nav.png" width="189" height="44"/>

        </div>

        <div class="nav">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="URL" alt="HOME">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="URL" alt="ABOUT US">ABOUT US</a></li>
                <li><a href="URL" alt="OUR SERVICES">OUR SERVICES</a></li>
                <li><a href="URL" alt="CONTACT US">CONTACT US</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>



    </div>

    <div class="content">

        <div class="contentBody">

        </div>

        <div class="sidebar1">

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="footer" >

    </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body{
    top:0;
    left:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0; 
    background-color:#666;  
}

.container{
    position:relative;
    margin-top: 0%;
    position:relative;
    width:1000px;
    margin:0px auto;
}

.header{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:900px;
    height:120px;
    background-color:#CFCA4C;
    margin:0px 50px 0px 50px;
}

.navContainer{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;

}

.miniNav{
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
}

.nav{
    float:left;
    max-width:900px;
    width:900px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    overfow:hidden;
    margin: 0 20px 0 50px;
}

ul.nav{
    list-style:none;    
    padding: 0px;
}

ul.nav li{
    display:inline;
    padding:0px;    
    float:left;
}



.content{
    float:left;
    width:900px;
    min-height:400px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    margin:0px 50px 0px 50px;
}

.footer{
    float:left;
    width:900px;
    height:80px;
    background-color:#CFCA4C;
    margin:0px 50px 0px 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both div and ul has class 'nav'. Ul with class nav should not have margins (they have already been added in div). So add:

```
ul.nav {margin: 0}
```

Comment: Wow, this did it, I didn't even realize I was calling the same class.  Yes, setting the margin to 0 or renaming the class fix the issue, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav {
     width: 850px;
 }
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kongr45gpen/a5Auj/

Answer (score 0):

What you really need to do is simply remove a lot of properties.

You should also set `.container` to `900px` instead of `1000px`, because that's how wide all the things inside it are.

You can remove almost all of the instances of `float: left` and `margin`.

Block-level elements (such as `div`s) will by default expand to fill the available width, so you don't need to specify `width: 900px` so many times. This isn't the behaviour if you `float: left` an element, but I've removed your instances of it.

So, bearing all that in mind, see: http://jsbin.com/ozemoy. Just one `width` is being set :)